# How to load image from documents directory/IPHONE

Tags: iphone, uiimage

I am saving the images when there is internet connection in my iphone.
Now i want to load the images which are saved in documents directory. I am getting the path, but the image is not displaying. Please help me in this.
Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
+(UIImage *) getImagewithName:(NSString*) imagepath
{
    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    UIImage *gimage=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",docDir,imagepath]];

    NSLog(@"%@/%@",docDir,imagepath);

    return gimage;
}

+(void)DownloadImage:(NSString*)ImagePath {
    if ([ImagePath isEqualToString:@""])
       return;

    UIImage *dimage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:/uploads/%@",ImagePath]]]];
    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"pathIMAGEPATHS:::::::%@",ImagePath);
    NSLog(@"path:::::::%@",docDir);
    NSArray *patharr=[ImagePath componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    NSString* Ext=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[patharr objectAtIndex:1]];
    NSString *FilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",docDir,ImagePath]];
    if([Ext isEqualToString:@"png"])
    {
        NSLog(@"saving png");

        NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(dimage)];
        [data1 writeToFile:FilePath atomically:YES];
    }
    else if([Ext isEqualToString:@"jpeg"])
    {
        NSLog(@"saving jpeg");
        //NSString *jpegFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.jpeg",docDir];
        NSData *data2 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(dimage, 1.0f)];//1.0f = 100% quality
        [data2 writeToFile:FilePath atomically:YES];
    }
    else 
    {
        NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(dimage)];
        [data1 writeToFile:FilePath atomically:YES];

    }
    NSLog(@"saving image done");

    [dimage release];

}
```

Comment: have you checked (easy to do with the simulator) if the image has been physically saved and can be opened with Preview? What I can see is that you never check if dimage, once downloaded from the network, is nil or not. If it is nil your code will keep going but finally saving an empty file. You should add a nil-check on dimage and exit with a NSLog(@"image not downloaded") and an early return.

Comment: Another good way of debugging interactions with the Documents directory is to turn on file sharing in your `Info.plist`.  Then you can open iTunes to browse the files and transfer them to your computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

viggio24 makes a good point. But moreover, this code seems incredibly complicated to do something incredibly simple. Why do you download to data, then turn it into an image, just to turn it back into data, and finally write it? And then you read it again and make a new image? Why not just download the file to disk and read it? `UIImage` will do all the work of managing PNG and JPEG for you. Something like:

```
+(void)downloadImage:(NSString*)imagePath {
    if ([imagePath isEqualToString:@""])
        return;

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://110.234.132.132/MBCMcAdmin/uploads" stringByAppendingPathComponent:imagePath]]];
    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    [data writeToFile:[docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:imagePath] atomically:YES];
}
```

This is still a horrible idea in most cases, though, since it blocks the calling thread. It's better to do this with `NSURLDownload` which will do it all for you in the background and tell you when it's done.

I'd simplify the code, and then follow viggio24's comments, making sure that you error check this stuff. You're probably just not reading the file correctly or failing to write it.